# Angularjs: If equals array

Tags: angularjs

I have an array: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Using ng-show (e.g. `ng-show="foo == bar"`), how would you determine if a number equals one of those numbers in the array?

Comment: Sounds like a job better suited for a directive.

Comment: @francisco.preller looking through the docs, you're right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say you have the array `foo` and the number is 118 so this should work

```
ng-show="foo.indexOf(118) != -1"
```

Comment: Thx. It seems to work but could you explain this to me? Why the '-1'?

Comment: -1 for `indexOf` means it doesn't exist in the array

Comment: Sure, the `indexOf` looks in the array the element (a number in this case) and returns the index, meaning the position of that element in the array. So if the array is something like [9,3,5,11] and you do [9,3,5,11].indexOf(5) the result would be 2 because 5 is in the position number 2 (remember the array are zero based). If it returns -1 it means that the element is not present in the array.

Comment: Just a warning, indexOf does not exist in some older browsers (most notably IE8 and below), so you will need to define it if you want to support old browsers.